# has worked / worked

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

I have been wondering what I should use between PP and PS in this particular context.

The last year, my friend bleached his teeth by a doctor, and today I want to do the same but I am puzzled and he tell me
" It will work because it worked for me" or "It will work because it has worked for me"

Indeed, even though the action is past, there is a relevance in the present. But to me the past simple version is better.

Comment: He _had his teeth bleached_ by a doctor (dentist?).

Comment: Both are fine.  Neither is preferable to the other. Take your choice. Note however that English speakers would generally say **....it's worked for me**, not "it has worked for me"..

Comment: @KateBunting yes dentist

Answer (score 1):

I would go with the first example. It is a little bit more natural sounding from a native speaker-perspective, and the second version with "has worked" suggests that the bleaching process is an ongoing thing rather than a one-time occurrence. Additionally, the sentence as a whole is a bit awkward because of what it implies. Just because the tooth bleaching worked for one person, this doesn't mean that it *will* automatically work for you. A better way to convey the same meaning might be

> I've had my teeth bleached and it worked for me. Therefore, it might be worth giving it a shot.

or

> Bleaching my teeth worked for me. It might work for you as well.

Comment: Strongly agree that "*it has worked for me*" suggests it continues to work, and implies "*so far*", which is not the intent. It worked for me (in the past) so it will work for you.